# there are two tables on a page, how can i import only one using importxml in google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

there are two tables on a page, how can I import only one using import XML in google sheets

link
https://www.ipowatch.in/p/ipo-subscription-numbers-status.html

I am using
`=IMPORTXML(H2, "//tr")`

where H2 has the link, it's a dynamic table where data changes every day.

But the result is returning two tables whereas I only want upper one.

if I am using
`=IMPORTXML(H2, "/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody")`

then its is return all data in a single row

This is my first post on stack overflow, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 1), "*", ))
```

and for 2nd table:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 2), "*", ))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this worked. I was using HTML before this but it was giving me disturbed formatted data.

Comment: also how can we add "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ORDER BY Col1 ASC" to this above function . i am using `=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(I2 & "?refresh=" & I6,I3,I4), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ORDER BY Col1 ASC")` earlier and its giving me desired results